# C - writing and reading from FIFO file in parallel - unexpected behaviour

Tags: c, pipe, fifo

I have two pipes to FIFO file, reader and writer. I open two terminals and write on the writer, and expect the text to appear on the reader. For some reason, I am experiencing very weird behavior - sometimes a space or some chars are added and I have no idea why. can someone help me?
I am attaching the reader and writer code.

reader:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024

struct sigaction sigHelp;
struct sigaction intAct;
struct sigaction termAct;
struct stat st;
int line;
char buf[BUF_SIZE];
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char *filePath = argv[1];
    assert (argc == 2);
    sigHelp.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    sigHelp.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset(&intAct.sa_mask);
    while(1) {
        int indicator = 1;
        while(indicator) {
            int statErr = stat(filePath, &st);
            if (statErr == 0) {
                if (!S_ISFIFO(st.st_mode)) {
                    printf("Error: file is not a FIFO file.\n");
                }
                else {
                    indicator = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (errno == ENOENT) { //wait for file
                    sleep(1);
                }
                else {
                    printf("Error checking file status - %s\n", strerror(errno));
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
        int intErr = sigaction(SIGINT, &sigHelp, &intAct);
        if(intErr == -1) {
            printf("Error: sigint action failed - %s\n" ,strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
        int termErr = sigaction(SIGTERM, &sigHelp, &termAct);
        if(termErr == -1) {
            printf("Error: sigterm action failed - %s\n" ,strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
        line = open(filePath, O_RDONLY, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO);
        assert(line != -1);
        while (1) {
            int readInd = read(line, buf, BUF_SIZE);
            if(readInd == -1){
                printf("Error: failed reading from FIFO file - %s\n", strerror(errno));
                close(line);
            }
            else if(readInd == 0) {
                break;
            }
            printf("%s ", buf);
        }
        close(line);
        int intE = sigaction(SIGINT, &intAct, NULL);
        if(intE == -1){
            printf("Error: sigint action failed - %s\n" ,strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
        int termE = sigaction(SIGTERM, &termAct, NULL);
        if(termE == -1){
            printf("Error: sigterm action failed - %s\n" ,strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

writer:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define LINE_SIZE 1024

struct sigaction sigAct;
const char* fileName;
int fifoFile;
int warnIndicator = 0;
struct stat st; 
mode_t mode;
void handle_signal(int signal);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    assert(argc == 2);
    fileName = argv[1];
    sigAct.sa_handler = &handle_signal; //opinter to function
    int si = sigaction(SIGINT, &sigAct, NULL); 
    if (si < 0) {
        printf("Error: sigint action failed - %s\n",strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    int stin = sigaction(SIGTERM, &sigAct, NULL);
    if (stin < 0) {
        printf("Error: sigterm action failed - %s\n",strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    int sp = sigaction(SIGPIPE, &sigAct, NULL);
    if (sp < 0) {
        printf("Error: sigpipe action failed - %s\n",strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    mode = ACCESSPERMS;
    int statSuc = stat(argv[1], &st);
    if (statSuc == -1) {
        if (errno != ENOENT) {
            printf("Error: stat failed - %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else { // stat success
        int fifoInd = S_ISFIFO(st.st_mode);
        if (fifoInd != 0) {
            fifoFile =  open(argv[1], O_WRONLY, mode);
        }
        else {
            int linkInd = unlink(argv[1]);
            if (linkInd == -1) {
                printf( "Error: unlink failed - %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
    int fifoInd = mkfifo(argv[1], mode);
    if (fifoInd == -1) {
        printf("Error: making fifo failed - %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    fifoFile =  open(argv[1], O_WRONLY, mode);
    char line[LINE_SIZE];
    while (fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
        write (fifoFile,line,strlen(line));
    }
    int unlinkSuc = unlink(argv[1]);
    if (unlinkSuc == -1) {
        printf( "Error: unlink failed - %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
        return -1;
    }
    close(fifoFile);
    return 0;
}
void handle_signal(int sign) { 
    if (sign == SIGPIPE || sign == SIGINT || sign == SIGTERM) {
        if (sign == SIGPIPE) {
            if (warnIndicator == 0) {
                printf("Error: writing to closed pipe \n");
                warnIndicator == 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            unlink(fileName);
            close(fifoFile);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks, and sorry if its too long.

Comment: what is your environment? (Linux, Windows)

Comment: when compiling always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` ).   The posted code,(on ubuntu linux 14.04) does not compile!  To start, insert the statement: `#define _GNU_SOURCE` at the beginning of each file (when on linux)

Comment: this line, in the writer, ` warnIndicator == 1;` causes the compiler to raise a warning: 'statement with no effect [ -Wunused-value]'

Comment: do not `unlink` the pipe, until after closing the pipe.

Comment: do not access command line parameters beyond `argv[0]` until after checking the value of `argc` to assure the command line parameter actually exists.  the function: `assert()` is ok for debugging but a very bad idea for production code.  Instead of `assert()` use something similar to: `if(2 != argc ) { printf( "USAGE: %s, <filename>\n", argv[0] ); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

Comment: there are several functions that should not be called inside a signal handler, `printf()` is one of those functions.  You might try: `fwrite()` instead.

Comment: note that the call to: `mkfifo()` manipulates the `mode` parameter using the value in the environment variable: `umask`, so it is usually a good idea to set `umask` just before calling `mkfifo()`

Comment: when calling the system functions, like `open()`, always check the returned code to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: strongly suggest, while performing initial debugging, to eliminate all the signal handling, except `SIGPIPE` until the named pipe communication works

Comment: The code is not careful about calling unlink() on some random file. You probably do not want to be doing that. Suggest just output a message and call exit(). Do this because the user has used an invalid command line parameter.

Answer (score 3):

```
write(fifoFile, line, strlen(line));
```

That is not writing the terminating NUL byte which the reader is expecting (since the reader treats it as a string). Change to:

```
write(fifoFile, line, strlen(line) + 1);
```